# Group and plot values from .gpx files with Python

Tags: python, gpx, tracking

I'm following [this](https://ocefpaf.github.io/python4oceanographers/blog/2014/08/18/gpx/) tutorial, and the code is supposed to iterate over multiple .gpx files to plot a chart that shows the distance grouped per month and year. It works, but the function seems to have an issue as it reads only the first .gpx file and I can't find where it fails:

```
import os
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from IPython.display import HTML
from glob import glob
import gpxpy

    #function definition
def load_run_data(gpx_path, filter=""):
    gpx_files = glob(os.path.join(gpx_path, filter + "*.gpx"))
    run_data = []
    for file_idx, gpx_file in enumerate(gpx_files):
        gpx = gpxpy.parse(open(gpx_file, 'r'))
        # Loop through tracks
        for track_idx, track in enumerate(gpx.tracks):
            track_name = track.name
            track_time = track.get_time_bounds().start_time
            track_length = track.length_3d()
            track_duration = track.get_duration()
            track_speed = track.get_moving_data().max_speed

        for seg_idx, segment in enumerate(track.segments):
            segment_length = segment.length_3d()
            for point_idx, point in enumerate(segment.points):
                run_data.append([file_idx, os.path.basename(gpx_file), track_idx, track_name,
                                 track_time, track_length, track_duration, track_speed,
                                 seg_idx, segment_length, point.time, point.latitude,
                                 point.longitude, point.elevation, segment.get_speed(point_idx)])
        return run_data


data = load_run_data(gpx_path='./gpx', filter="")
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['File_Index', 'File_Name', 'Index', 'Name',
                              'Time', 'Length', 'Duration', 'Max_Speed',
                              'Segment_Index', 'Segment_Length', 'Point_Time', 'Point_Latitude',
                              'Point_Longitude', 'Point_Elevation', 'Point_Speed'])

HTML(df.head().to_html(max_cols=4))

#conversion of distance to km
cols = ['File_Index', 'Time', 'Length', 'Duration', 'Max_Speed']
tracks = df[cols].copy()
tracks['Length'] /= 1e3
tracks.drop_duplicates(inplace=True)
tracks.head()

#add year and month columns, group the values
tracks['Year'] = tracks['Time'].apply(lambda x: x.year)
tracks['Month'] = tracks['Time'].apply(lambda x: x.month)
tracks_grouped = tracks.groupby(['Year','Month'])
tracks_grouped.describe().head()

#plot the chart
figsize=(7, 3.5)
tracks_grouped = tracks.groupby(['Year', 'Month'])
ax = tracks_grouped['Length'].sum().plot(kind='bar', figsize=figsize)
xlabels = [text.get_text() for text in  ax.get_xticklabels()]
ax.set_xticklabels(xlabels, rotation=70)
_ = ax.set_ylabel('Distance (km)')
plt.show()
```

Comment: It is a pure Python problem: what is the result of `gpx_files = glob(os.path.join(gpx_path, filter + "*.gpx"))`?

Comment: @gene Well, this could go beyond my knowledge but _apparently_ it returns a list with the .gpx files in the project folder: `['./gpx\\file_1.gpx', './gpx\\file_2.gpx', ... ]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your third `for` block is wrongly indented (same level as the second `for` block) because it depends on the variable `track` which is defined in that second `for` loop. So if the second loop fails you will run into troubles:  `UnboundLocalError: local variable 'track' referenced before assignment`. That's why you probably need to nest it deeper.

I added two prints statement for more verbosity, and because I don't have some *.gpx* files at hand, I set a `PLOT` trigger before plotting, which I personally set to `False` in the following code.

Same goes for the code that loop over the `tracks`; I don't have your *.gpx* file structure at hand.

But once I run the code on 3 dummy *.gpx* files, I got this which is printed in stdout:

```py
Processing file 0: ./gpx/gpx_path_003.gpx...
Processing file 1: ./gpx/gpx_path_001.gpx...
Processing file 2: ./gpx/gpx_path_002.gpx...
```

Here's the code:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import os
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from IPython.display import HTML
from glob import glob
import gpxpy

#function definition
def load_run_data(gpx_path, filter=""):
    gpx_files = glob(os.path.join(gpx_path, filter + "*.gpx"))
    run_data = []
    for file_idx, gpx_file in enumerate(gpx_files):
        print(f"Processing file {file_idx}: {gpx_file}...")
        gpx = gpxpy.parse(open(gpx_file, 'r'))
        # Loop through tracks
        for track_idx, track in enumerate(gpx.tracks):
            print(f"Processing track {track_idx}: {track}...")
            track_name = track.name
            track_time = track.get_time_bounds().start_time
            track_length = track.length_3d()
            track_duration = track.get_duration()
            track_speed = track.get_moving_data().max_speed

            for seg_idx, segment in enumerate(track.segments):
                segment_length = segment.length_3d()
                for point_idx, point in enumerate(segment.points):
                    run_data.append([
                        file_idx, os.path.basename(gpx_file), track_idx, track_name,
                        track_time, track_length, track_duration, track_speed,
                        seg_idx, segment_length, point.time, point.latitude,
                        point.longitude, point.elevation, segment.get_speed(point_idx)
                    ])

    return run_data


data = load_run_data(gpx_path='./gpx', filter="")
df = pd.DataFrame(
    data,
    columns = [
        'File_Index', 'File_Name', 'Index', 'Name',
        'Time', 'Length', 'Duration', 'Max_Speed',
        'Segment_Index', 'Segment_Length', 'Point_Time', 'Point_Latitude',
        'Point_Longitude', 'Point_Elevation', 'Point_Speed'
    ]
)

HTML(df.head().to_html(max_cols=4))

#conversion of distance to km
cols = ['File_Index', 'Time', 'Length', 'Duration', 'Max_Speed']
tracks = df[cols].copy()
tracks['Length'] /= 1e3
tracks.drop_duplicates(inplace=True)
tracks.head()

#add year and month columns, group the values
tracks['Year'] = tracks['Time'].apply(lambda x: x.year)
tracks['Month'] = tracks['Time'].apply(lambda x: x.month)
tracks_grouped = tracks.groupby(['Year','Month'])
tracks_grouped.describe().head()

#plot the chart
PLOT=False
if PLOT:
    figsize=(7, 3.5)
    tracks_grouped = tracks.groupby(['Year', 'Month'])
    ax = tracks_grouped['Length'].sum().plot(kind='bar', figsize=figsize)
    xlabels = [text.get_text() for text in  ax.get_xticklabels()]
    ax.set_xticklabels(xlabels, rotation=70)
    _ = ax.set_ylabel('Distance (km)')
    plt.show()
```

So from this point, the rest of the code only depends on your file content.

You can also use [`glob.iglob`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/glob.html#glob.iglob) if you need to iterate through many files, it may be more convenient to use.

Comment: so was the issue only wrong formatting?? I need to check better next time...